# Data in excel not sorting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort the data in my excel but it is not getting sorted.I have used the below code in VBA

```
Set total_data = Worksheets("CREATE_INFOSOURCES").Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlToRight))

Set sorting_column = Worksheets("CREATE_INFOSOURCES").Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown))


total_data.Sort Key1:=sorting_column, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

I want to sort the data in ascending order based on column A and my data is filled from A5 row.

Please tell where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

```
Public Function sort()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim RangeSort As Range
Dim RangeKey As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("CREATE_INFOSOURCES")
Lrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'one range that includes all columns do sort
Set RangeSort = ws.Range("A5:A" & Lrow)

With ws
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=RangeKey, _
                         Order:=xlAscending, _
                         DataOption:=xlSortNormal
End With

With ws.Sort
    .SetRange RangeSort
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Apply
End With

'clean up
ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Set ws = Nothing

End Function
```